# Sending a GET to Avis test environment

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

newbie here so please be gentle.

In order to improve my javascript/GAS knowledge, I am trying to write some simple functions to request car rental locations, availability and rates from Avis Budget Group (ABG).

I signed up with their developers portal (https://developer.avis.com/) and got my access details, which I used to write a "getAccessToken" function which works correctly (and I was able to pull back an array of rental locations using my client details + the token).

However, when I try to submit a GET request as follows, it fails out and I really can't see why...

// This successfully returns my token for OAuth

```
  var authToken = getAccessToken('','');
```

// URL as per Avis documentation

```
  var url='stage.abgapiservices.com:443/cars/catalog/v1/vehicles/rates';
  var bOpt=false;
```

// client_id obfusticated for obvious reasons

```
  var options = {
    'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+  authToken, 'client_id': '00000000'},
    'method': 'GET',
    'age': '32',
    'brand': 'Avis',
    'country_code': 'GB',
    'dropoff_date': '2020-10-20T12:00Z',
    'dropoff_location': 'castleford',
    'pickup_date': '2020-10-13T12:00Z',
    'pickup_location': 'castleford',
    'rate_code': 'cai',
    'vehicle_class_code': 'A',
    'muteHttpExceptions': bOpt
  };
```

// I got the rate_code value by performing the exact same search on the production Avis website and inspecting the underlying HTML

// Here's where it fails, returning "Bad request"

```
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
```

// This is where I would store the rates it over got this far !!!

```
  var rates = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

Any pointers on stupid mistakes would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply (even though it will take me some effort to properly understand it !).  Just to note, I used exact same credentials to query Avis locations and that works perfectly so I don't think it's an authentication issue...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Thanks, I would be very happy to co-operate in finding a solution. However, you should obtain your own client_id and client_secret from Avis. This is a 5-minuyr process. When testing, you can use yours and I can use mine - no need to share them :)`, I couldn't understand your current issue.

Comment: But, I would like to support you. So, I would like to try to understand your current issue. When I could correctly understand your current issue, I would like to answer it. So, in the current stage, I have to delete my answer. When I could correctly understand your current issue, I would like to answer it.